# What are the correct filenames for device configs in /etc/network/interfaces.d

Tags: ubuntu, networking

It's easy enough to find references to creating network configuration files name eth0.cfg

But the are the correct filenames for other devices i.e. eth0:0

I can't find any documentation to explain the naming structure.

Answer (score 0):

There is no correct naming structure, you can name them whatever you want.

Typically, they are included into the main `interfaces` file with a line like this:

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*.cfg
```

which means that all files ending with `.cfg` will included.

However, in practice I would name them according to the device name, e.g. `eth0:1.cfg`.